# how many versions of caching can you have in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library, sitecore7.2

We have upgraded our Sitecore to 7.2 and we realize the size of Sitecore is growing. About 1/5 of the amount of space that is taken up is based in stored cache/binary code. For example when we update an image, Sitecore still stores the previous image in its memory which adds to the MB total. I am curious is there a way to clean out any previous media files when publishing or is there a setting in Sitecore that allows a certain amount of versions of stored files? I know in the right corner there is an arrow that stores previous versions of the entire file, that is not what I'm worried about I'm more worried about media storage or the binary memory.

Comment: Are you talking about database size or the media cache on disk that you are worried about?

Comment: both actually, whatever I can do to save space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore caches the media items to `/App_Data/MediaCache` for performance reasons and saves a trip back to the database. By default, any media over 90 days old gets deleted when the CleanupAgent is run:

```xml
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent" method="Run" interval="06:00:00">
  <!-- Specifies files to be cleaned up.
       If rolling="true", [minCount] and [maxCount] will be ignored.
       [minAge] and [maxAge] must be specified as [days.]hh:mm:ss. The default value
       of [minAge] is 30 minutes.
       [strategy]: number of files within hour, day, week, month, year
       [recursive=true|false]: descend folders?
  -->
  <files hint="raw:AddCommand">
    ...
    <remove folder="/App_Data/MediaCache" pattern="*.*" maxAge="90.00:00:00" recursive="true"/>
  </files>
```

You could reduce the `maxAge` so something less to force it to clear up more often. Disk space is cheap though, but it obviously depends on the size of your media library. You should consider [using a CDN to serve your media](http://allthingssitecore.com/2014/03/26/integrating-a-cdn-into-your-sitecore-solution/) if it is very large.

With regards to versioning, you can have an unlimited number of versions, although Sitecore recommends not keeping more than 10 versions per item.

By default, Media Items are uploaded using the `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned` templates, in which case the images are overwritten each time you upload a new image. If you use the Advanced Upload dialog and select the "versioned" option or set `Media.UploadAsVersionableByDefault="true"` in config then `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned` template will be used in which case you can you will end up with multiple versions. Check which template is being used and check your config if versions are not required.

You could [implement a rule to deleted old versions when an item is saved](http://www.sitecore.net/EN-GB/community/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/08/rules-engine-actions-to-remove-old-versions-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms) or implement a scheduled task to do the same. Also take a look at the [Sitecore Version Pruner](http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/introducing-the-sitecore-version-pruner-shared-source-module/) module but I suspect you do not want to serialize the files to disk since you end up back at the same issue of disk space.

Comment: @Keith I should add, the issue I have normally seen with file size is to do with backups. Make sure your DB backup strategy is correct, maybe full once a week and then incremental for the rest, and you are not backing up the MediaCache or temp folders.